# Xpath Rule: Trying to pull list of links under a specific heading tag on a webpage

Tags: xpath, data-extraction

Thank you in advance for your time and support.

I am in the process of QA'ing a new site launch and as part of that I am running a crawling tool called Screaming Frog to assess parts of the site's structure.

The crawling tool is quite powerful and allows for custom extractions via Xpath which I am trying to make use of now.

The issue I am having is that I would like to pull the specific links located within certain recirc modules.  The modules themselves unfortunately do not have proper div labels... so I have to instead use the H3 module header as my identifier.

```
<h3>Further Reading:</h3>   
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
      <li>Link 4</li>
      <li>Link 5</li>
   </ul>
```

I would like to be able to extract the link values inside of the Further Reading list.

Is it possible to find the specific Further Reading header in the doc and then pull the links in a single Xpath request?

Thank you again.  I am really enjoying learning about xpath and reading about it here on Stack Overflow.

Regards,

Darryl

Answer (score 0):

you can use `contains()` xpath function. and xpath axes.

```
//h3[text()='Further Reading:']/following-sibling::ul[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `following-sibling` axis:

```
//h3/following-sibling::ul/li
```

or if you want be some specific:

```
//h3[text() = 'Further Reading:']/following-sibling::ul/li
```

Comment: You guys are amazing.  Thank you.    One more wrinkle.  When I pull in the data I have 4 options:  Extract text, Function value, Extract inner html, Extract HTML Element.  I would like to be able to pull in the href value AND the text for the link... but not the full html element.   I can grab the text no problem now based on your help above (thanks again).... but if I wanted to extract the href link itself (the page being linked to)... how would the above xpath change for that?   This is awesome... so much fun and valuable.  Thanks again.

Comment: I got it!   I added a/@href and it pulled it all in.   THANK YOU SO MUCH!   Really appreciated!